# JOptionPane.showMessageDialog like System.out.printf

Tags: java

How can I do that `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog` be like `System.out.printf`?

I tried something like that:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your name is %s", name);
```

But I get error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see the docs for what you can supply to this method: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html

But what you could do in your case is:

to use '+' to concatenate the strings:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your name is" + name);
```

or using String.Format:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, String.format("Your name is %s",name));
```

Assuming that name is a String and has a value defined.

Comment: +1, the most direct solution. String.format(...) was also the method I was looking for to do simple token replacement.

Comment: Yes, but is it possible with this symbol - %s ? (I don't know how it calls.

Comment: String.format(...) is what you're looking for - does the example above not help?